# Figure caption line numbers with achemso package

Tags: floats, captions, achemso, linenumber

I have written an article for a journal of the American Chemical Society using the package achemso (Texlive 2020). After the submission I have been asked to supply also the pdf file with the line numbers.
I put the `\usepackage{lineno}` in the preamble, the command `\linenumbers` in the text and the command `\internallinenumbers` before the `\caption` within the `\begin{figure]` environment.
Everything seems fine but looking better to the results I realized that in the last line of every figure caption there were two numbers overlapped.
This problem is present also using the achemso-demo.tex file and inserting the instructions for the line numbers as reported above.
Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.
Here a small example where after compiling put overlapped the numbers 14 and 15 on the line of the figure caption.

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use modern font encodings
\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}
\author{I. Ken Groupleader}
\email{i.k.groupleader@unknown.uu}
\phone{+123 (0)123 4445556}
\fax{+123 (0)123 4445557}
\affiliation[Unknown University]
{Department of Chemistry, Unknown University, Unknown Town}
\title[An \textsf{achemso} demo]
  {A demonstration of the \textsf{achemso} \LaTeX\
   class}
\abbreviations{IR,NMR,UV}
\keywords{American Chemical Society, \LaTeX}
\usepackage{lineno}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers

\begin{abstract}
  This is an example document for the \textsf{achemso} document
  class, intended for submissions to the American Chemical Society
  for publication.
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
This is a paragraph of text to fill the introduction of the
demonstration file.

\section{Results and discussion}

\subsection{Outline}

The document layout should follow the style of the journal concerned.
Where appropriate, sections and subsections should be added in the
normal way.

\subsection{Floats}

New float types are automatically set up by the class file.  The
means graphics are included as follows (Scheme~\ref{sch:example}).  As
illustrated, the float is ``here'' if possible.
\begin{scheme}
  Your scheme graphic would go here: \texttt{.eps} format\\
  for \LaTeX\, or \texttt{.pdf} (or \texttt{.png}) for pdf\LaTeX\\
  \textsc{ChemDraw} files are best saved as \texttt{.eps} files:\\
  these can be scaled without loss of quality, and can be\\
  converted to \texttt{.pdf} files easily using \texttt{eps2pdf}.\\
  %\includegraphics{graphic}
  \caption{An example scheme}
  \label{sch:example}
\end{scheme}

\begin{figure}
  As well as the standard float types \texttt{table}\\
  and \texttt{figure}, the class also recognises\\
  \texttt{scheme}, \texttt{chart} and \texttt{graph}.
\internallinenumbers 
  \caption{An example figure}
  \label{fgr:example}
\end{figure}

Charts, figures and schemes do not necessarily have to be labelled or
captioned.  However, tables should always have a title. It is
possible to include a number and label for a graphic without any
title, using an empty argument to the \texttt{\textbackslash caption}
macro.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Alby, you have asked questions before, so you should know what's needed such that people can help: A small sample code that shows the problem. Please ...

Comment: The small sample code is to take the file achemso-demo.tex put \usepackage{lineno} in the preamble, put \linenumbers after \begin{document} and \internallinenumbers before the \caption of figure 1. I will try to prepare a short file from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff done in `\caption` seems to confuse the `lineno` package. Since the achemso document class loads the caption package one can try to move the `\internallinenumbers` inside the caption text (instead of putting it in front of `\caption`), for example by declaring and applying it as caption font:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use modern font encodings
\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}
\author{I. Ken Groupleader}
\email{i.k.groupleader@unknown.uu}
\phone{+123 (0)123 4445556}
\fax{+123 (0)123 4445557}
\affiliation[Unknown University]
{Department of Chemistry, Unknown University, Unknown Town}
\title[An \textsf{achemso} demo]
  {A demonstration of the \textsf{achemso} \LaTeX\
   class}
\abbreviations{IR,NMR,UV}
\keywords{American Chemical Society, \LaTeX}
\usepackage{lineno}
\DeclareCaptionFont{linenumbers}{\internallinenumbers}
\captionsetup[figure]{font+=linenumbers} % use \internallinenumbers inside figure caption texts
\begin{document}
\linenumbers

\begin{abstract}
  This is an example document for the \textsf{achemso} document
  class, intended for submissions to the American Chemical Society
  for publication.
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
This is a paragraph of text to fill the introduction of the
demonstration file.

\section{Results and discussion}

\subsection{Outline}

The document layout should follow the style of the journal concerned.
Where appropriate, sections and subsections should be added in the
normal way.

\subsection{Floats}

New float types are automatically set up by the class file.  The
means graphics are included as follows (Scheme~\ref{sch:example}).  As
illustrated, the float is ``here'' if possible.
\begin{scheme}
  Your scheme graphic would go here: \texttt{.eps} format\\
  for \LaTeX\, or \texttt{.pdf} (or \texttt{.png}) for pdf\LaTeX\\
  \textsc{ChemDraw} files are best saved as \texttt{.eps} files:\\
  these can be scaled without loss of quality, and can be\\
  converted to \texttt{.pdf} files easily using \texttt{eps2pdf}.\\
  %\includegraphics{graphic}
  \caption{An example scheme}
  \label{sch:example}
\end{scheme}

\begin{figure}
  As well as the standard float types \texttt{table}\\
  and \texttt{figure}, the class also recognises\\
  \texttt{scheme}, \texttt{chart} and \texttt{graph}.
%\internallinenumbers => moved to caption font "linenumbers"
  \caption{An example figure}
  \label{fgr:example}
\end{figure}

Charts, figures and schemes do not necessarily have to be labelled or
captioned.  However, tables should always have a title. It is
possible to include a number and label for a graphic without any
title, using an empty argument to the \texttt{\textbackslash caption}
macro.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This elegant solution solved the problem!!!